Neural net flips behaviour with layer count
I wrote a simple neural net and i am too confused with its behaviour. I try a simple training set with Relu-Activation which has to predict 0.5 for input 1 and 0 for input 0. It works with layerDimension = {1,10,10,1} but not with {1,10,1} or {1,10,10,10,1}.
Here is my code:
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Net {
    Layer inputLayer;
    Layer outputLayer;
    ArrayList<Layer> hiddenLayers;
    double learningRate;

     public Net(int[] layerDimensions){
        this.learningRate = learningRate;
        inputLayer = new Layer();
        hiddenLayers = new ArrayList<>();
        outputLayer = new Layer();
        for(int i = 0; i< layerDimensions[0]; i++){
            inputLayer.nodes.add(new Node(new Relu()));
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < layerDimensions.length-1; i++){
            Layer hiddenLayer = new Layer();
            for(int j = 0; j< layerDimensions[i]; j++){
                hiddenLayer.nodes.add(new Node(new Relu()));
            }
            hiddenLayers.add(hiddenLayer);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <  layerDimensions[layerDimensions.length-1]; i++){
            outputLayer.nodes.add(new Node(new Relu()));
        }
        addConnections();
    }
    public double[] predict(double[] input){
        for(int i = 0; i < inputLayer.nodes.size(); i++){
            inputLayer.nodes.get(i).output = input[i];
        }
        for(Layer hiddenLayer : hiddenLayers){
            hiddenLayer.calcInput();
        }
        outputLayer.calcInput();
        return outputLayer.getOutput();
    }

    public double training(double[][] input, double[][] target, double learningRate, int repetitions) {
        this.learningRate = learningRate;
        double accuracy = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < repetitions; r++) {
            accuracy = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

                // Forward pass
                double[] output = predict(input[i]);

                // Calculate error for output layer
                for (int j = 0; j < outputLayer.nodes.size(); j++) {
                    Node outputNode = outputLayer.nodes.get(j);
                    double error = 0.5* Math.pow(target[i][j] - output[j],2);
                    outputNode.error = error * outputNode.activationFunction.phiStrich(outputNode.net);
                }
                // Backpropagate the error to hidden layers
                for (int l = hiddenLayers.size() - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
                    Layer hiddenLayer = hiddenLayers.get(l);
                    for (Node hiddenNode : hiddenLayer.nodes) {
                        hiddenNode.error = 0;
                        for (Edge edge : hiddenNode.outgoing) {
                            hiddenNode.error += edge.weight * edge.targetNode.error;
                        }
                        hiddenNode.error *= hiddenNode.activationFunction.phiStrich(hiddenNode.net);
                    }
                }
                // Update weights and biases for output layer
                updateWeights(learningRate, outputLayer);

                // Update weights and biases for hidden layers
                for (Layer hiddenLayer : hiddenLayers) {
                    updateWeights(learningRate, hiddenLayer);
                }
                updateWeights(learningRate,inputLayer);
                // Calculate accuracy
                double mse = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
                    mse += Math.pow(target[i][j] - output[j], 2);
                }
                accuracy += mse / output.length;
            }
            accuracy /= input.length;
        }
        return accuracy;
    }

    private void updateWeights(double learningRate, Layer layer) {
        for (Node node : layer.nodes) {
            for (Edge edge : node.incoming) {
                edge.deltaWeight = -learningRate * node.error * edge.targetNode.output;
                edge.weight += edge.deltaWeight;
            }
            node.bias += -learningRate * node.error;
        }
    }

    private void addConnections(){
        for(Node inputNode: inputLayer.nodes){
            for(Node hiddenNode: hiddenLayers.get(0).nodes){
                Edge connection = new Edge(inputNode, hiddenNode);
                inputNode.outgoing.add(connection);
                hiddenNode.incoming.add(connection);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < hiddenLayers.size(); i++) {
            for(Node hiddenNode : hiddenLayers.get(i).nodes){
                for(Node previousNode : hiddenLayers.get(i-1).nodes){
                    Edge connection = new Edge(previousNode, hiddenNode);
                    previousNode.outgoing.add(connection);
                    hiddenNode.incoming.add(connection);
                }
            }
        }
        for(Node outputNode: outputLayer.nodes){
            for(Node hiddenNode: hiddenLayers.get(hiddenLayers.size()-1).nodes){
                Edge connection = new Edge(hiddenNode, outputNode);
                hiddenNode.outgoing.add(connection);
                outputNode.incoming.add(connection);
            }
        }
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Layer {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;

    public Layer(){
        nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public void calcInput(){
        for(Node node : nodes){
            node.net = 0;
            for(Edge connection : node.incoming){
                node.net += connection.sourceNode.output * connection.weight;
            }
            node.activate();
        }
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            double net = 0;
            for (Edge edge : node.incoming) {
                net += edge.weight * edge.sourceNode.output;
            }
            net += node.bias;
            node.net = net;
            node.output = node.activationFunction.phi(net);
        }
    }

    public double[] getOutput(){
        double[] result = new double[nodes.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){
            result[i] = nodes.get(i).output;
        }
        return result;
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node {
    ArrayList<Edge> outgoing;
    ArrayList<Edge> incoming;
    double net = 0;
    double bias;
    double output;
    double error;
    Aktivierungsfunktion activationFunction;

    public Node(Aktivierungsfunktion activationFunction){
        outgoing = new ArrayList<>();
        incoming = new ArrayList<>();
        this.activationFunction = activationFunction;
    }

    public void activate(){
        net += bias;
        output = activationFunction.phi(net);
    }
}

import java.util.Random;

public class Edge {
    Node sourceNode;
    Node targetNode;
    public Edge(Node source, Node target){
        this.sourceNode = source;
        this.targetNode = target;
        weight = new Random().nextDouble() * 0.5;
    }

    double weight;
    double deltaWeight;
}


public class Sigmoid extends Aktivierungsfunktion
{    
    public double phi(double x){
        return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    }

    public double phiStrich(double x){
        double phiVonX = phi(x);
        return phiVonX * (1 - phiVonX);
    }
}

public class Relu extends Aktivierungsfunktion
{
    private final double alpha = 0.01;
    public double phi(double x){
        if (x > 0) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return alpha * x;
        }
    }
    public double phiStrich(double x){
        if (x > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return alpha;
        }
    }
}



public abstract class Aktivierungsfunktion
{
    public abstract double phi(double x);

    public abstract double phiStrich(double x);
}


import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Net net = new Net(new int[] {1,10,10,1});
        double[][] input = {
                {0.0},
                {1.0},
                {1.0},
                {0.0},
        };
        double[][] target = {
                {0.0},
                {1.0},
                {1.0},
                {0.0}
        };
        double accuracy = net.training(input,target,0.01, 1000);
        System.out.println(accuracy);
        for (double[] in : input) {
            double[] out = net.predict(in);
            System.out.println("Input: " + Arrays.toString(in) + " Output: " + Arrays.toString(out));
        }
    }

}

I tried to simplify the problem with an input 0 -> target 0 and input 1 -> target 1.
When i change the activation function to Sigmoid, the predicted values go near a constant value, independend from the given input.
How could i could debug this?
